# Determining probabilities Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, mathematical-modeling, markov-process

If I have a Markov Chain $X_0, X_1, X_2 \dots$ that has a transition probability matrix

$
\textbf{P} = \matrix{~ & 0 & 1 & 2 \cr
              0 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.5 \cr
              1 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.4 \cr
              2 & 0.5 & 0.2 & 0.3\cr
                            }
$

and initial distribution $p_0=0.5$ and $p_1=0.5$.  I am supposed to determine probabilites Pr{X2=0} and Pr{X3=0}.

Would I use conditional probability to solve this or is there a simpler way.  I feel like I am overcomplicating thing because I am trying to use conditional probability but I don't have enough information to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Pr( X_2=0)=\sum_{i=0}^{2}Pr(X_2=0,X_0=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{2}Pr(X_2=0|X_0=i)Pr(X_0=i)$$
$$Pr(X_2=0|X_0=i)=(P^2)_{i,0}$$
These should be enough information for you to complete the question.